# What is the best way to get Category-info and Article-info at same time from mysql/php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a simple newspaper-site, due to schoolwork. I have two tables in my database.

**Categories**
[CategoryID, CategoryName, ParentID (which points to cat.id)]

**Article**
[ArticleID, Heading, Teasertext, Content, Date, Category(which is foreign key to CategoryID)]

On the first page im pulling out the latest articles written, and below each article has to have a link to the article (which is based on index.php?name=CategoryName&parent=ParentID).

I need to withdraw the relevant info about CategoryName and ParentID from the Category-info in Articles-table.

Im stuck on how to combine the two queries in to one. Im wondering if you have any idea´s on how to solve it?

This is what I got.

```
function display_articles($link)
{

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Article ORDER BY Date DESC");

                if (!$result)
                {
                    $error = 'Error fetching Articles: ' . mysqli_error($link);
                    exit();
                }


                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $Heading[] = $row['Heading'];
                    $Teasertext[] = $row['Teasertext'];
                    $Date[] = $row['Date'];
                }


                if (isset($Heading))
                {
                    for ($i=0; $i<count($Heading); $i++)
                    {

                        echo '<div class="frontpage"><h2>' .htmlspecialchars($Heading[$i], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"). '</h2>'; 
                        echo htmlspecialchars($Date[$i], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
                        echo '<p class="Teasertext"> ' .htmlspecialchars($Teasertext[$i], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"). '</p></div>';
                        echo '<a href="index.php?name='                 
                    }
                }

}
```

Comment: You are currently only have one query in your sample. So what two queries are you trying to combine?  Have you read any MySQL/SQL documentation?  Do you know how to use JOINs?

Comment: Evidently I have not. I will read up on it, tnx!

Comment: You also might want to not fall into the habit of using `SELECT *`.  In my experience there are very few times when you actually NEED all columns of data in a query. While using `SELECT *` might seem like a simple way to write code, it is acutually going to make your application potentially handle more data than it needs to, slow down performance in working with your result set and consuming more memory than necessary along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, c.CategoryName, c.ParentID 
FROM 
    Article AS a 
    INNER JOIN Category AS c on a.category = c.categoryId
ORDER BY a.Date DESC
```

Comment: @MichaelScott I suggest you to study SQL, check online tutorials. The usage of `Join` is fundamental in most database tasks

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT 
         a.*,c.* 
FROM 
         Article a LEFT JOIN 
         Categories c on (a.category=c.categoryid) 
ORDER BY 
         a.Date DESC
```